# CS1503 Cannot convert Matrix to MatrixOrder

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# programming. I would like to run a simple test in MVS for Matrix calculation code as attached.

However I obtained the following errors:

1) Error    CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix' to 'System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder'

2) Error    CS0019  Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Matrix' and 'Matrix'

I had tried looking for solutions, but couldn't resolve this errors.

Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.7.2
Output Type: Console Application

Please advise.
Thank You.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Project2

{
    public class MatrixCalculation
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        }

        private void MultiplicationExample()
        {
            Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
            Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);

            // matrixResult is equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
          Matrix matrixResult = Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);

            // matrixResult2 is also
            // equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
            Matrix matrixResult2 = matrix1 * matrix2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using a `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix` instead of a `System.Windows.Media.Matrix`.

The [`System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix.Multiply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.multiply?view=netframework-4.8) method takes one or two parameters. The first one being a `Matrix` and the optional second one a `MatrixOrder`.

Remove this line:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
```

If the error persists, the you're probably referencing the wrong assembly.

If you're using Visual Studio

1. Right click your project's references
2. Click on '*Add Reference*'
3. Search for *WindowsBase* and select it

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply! However after I removed the using System.Drawing.Drawing2D, new errors were shown. 1) Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Matrix' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) & 2) Error CS0103 The name 'Matrix' does not exist in the current context. I had added the reference: PresentationCore, System.Windows, System.Drawing to the project reference. The errors still pop out. Any advice on this? Thank you.

Comment: I have tried inserting the line using PresentationCore, eventually more errors pop out.

Comment: Ah ok you need to reference WindowsBase.dll. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help! It worked! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the namespace `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`, you could do the multiplication like the following:

```
matrix1.Multiply(matrix2); //matrix1 will have the result.
```

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.multiply?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will look into the reference link you provided. I'm still new and learning C#, this reference could bring me to another level of programming Matrix calculations. Currently the above solutions provided by C.Champagne worked (using System.Windows.Media.Matrix, added reference WIndowsBase). I will try out System.Drawing.Drawing2D namespace later. Really appreciate your help! Thank you!